# Integral of a Matrix Equation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, exponential-function, matrix-calculus

Given:
$$\int_0^t e^{-x}Be^{(A+B)x}dx$$
where $A,B$ are matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

How do you compute the definite integral?

I attempted to apply integration by parts, however I kept going in circles do to $e^x$

That is, I let 
$$\text{d}v = e^{-x}dx$$
and
$$u = Be^{(A+B)x}$$

Is there a simple trick I should be applying to avoid this?

Thanks!

**Extension**:

What if:
$$\int_0^t e^{-Ax}Be^{(A+B)x}dx$$
where $A,B$ are general matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple trick:
$$
\int_0^t e^{-x}Be^{(A+B)x}dx = 
\int_0^t B(e^{-x}\cdot I)e^{(A+B)x}dx = 
\int_0^t Be^{-Ix}e^{(A+B)x}dx = 
\int_0^t Be^{(A+B-I)x}dx.
$$

Comment: if $e^{-x}$ was instead $e^{-Ax}$ would a similar property hold? ie. replace $I$ with $A$?

Comment: That would only work if A and B commute

Comment: That makes sense, is there another 'trick' for when they don' commute? I modified the question to be slightly more clear

Comment: @Jack If you're really interested in that question, you should make a new post about it.